# How to send parameter to a winform appication from a asp.net page and get string in return

Tags: asp.net, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Hi i want to use windows form application in way like an api from an asp.net page?
And examples... please share.

OR

i want to call a windows form application and pass values to it 4 string values , and after the work done is completed by the form application, return a String that will have html back to the webpage to display?

And ideas , please help.

Main thing i want to know : i know how to call a process using ..net ,

```
   1- How will i send parameters?
   2- How will i catch parameters at my windows form application.
   3- How will i send parameters back to the page on windows form application .exit.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend not doing this.  It would be better to redesign your Windows Forms application so that your logic was in a separate assembly (DLL).

You could then reference this assembly from your ASP.Net project, and directly use the logic.  This would be far cleaner than trying to bridge to a desktop application.

Comment: The thing i require is a webbrowser control to load something and wait until the work is finished and when results appear return them to the website , like bookin hotels or finding price script etc....so i need to have a windows form app for that ? or not :S me nt sure i am nt that skilled in logics

Comment: @EhsanKayani Instead of using a WebBrowser, you can use WebRequest or WebClient, etc.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx

Comment: @EhsanKayani Also, its best if you can find an API for the site in question instead of trying to work off their public facing site...

Comment: Yes i am aware of that but under some circumstances i cannot use none of those , as some fields need to be filled and i cannot see the calls to interpret them in my request , so webbrowser is a must ....

Comment: @EhsanKayani WebBrowser is going to require running on a desktop - you're going to find that it's just not going to work, at least not in a reliable fashion.  Better to take the time to figure out the right API...

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best practice but if you must:

Call your win app passing the string parameters separated with spaces:

```
D:\...\MyApp.exe param1 param2 param3 param4
```

The executable can handle the parameters in the Main function:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string p1 = args[0];
  string p2 = args[1];
  string p3 = args[2];
  string p4 = args[3];

     ...
}
```

Use the `System.Environment.ExitCode` prior to returning to pass a value back to the calling process.